# TryUpdateModelAsync() fails without saying why

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a `TryUpdateModelAsync` call that, upon failing, simply returns false. It's not obvious why it's failing. How can I get more information?

```
if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<ComputerFile>(
    computerFileToUpdate,
    "computerfile",
    f => f.FileName, f => f.ContentDescription, f => f.SourceItemID, f => f.FileTypeID,
    f => f.CreatedOnDate, f => f.CreatedByID, f => f.ModifiedOnDate, f => f.ModifiedByID))
{
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return RedirectToPage("./Index");
}

return Page();
```

Answer (score 5):

I hope this helps you can just use 
ModelState.IsValid                                                                     and by using this you will get the perfect idea about what are the exact errors

```
var validationErrors = ModelState.Values.Where(E => E.Errors.Count > 0)
.SelectMany(E => E.Errors)
.Select(E => E.ErrorMessage)
.ToList();
```

Comment: Wonderful, Ishwar. Just what I was missing! Many thanks!

Comment: .net6's Nullable requires string? instead of string for nullable strings.